# Use of inner join seems to cause entries in a #temp table to disappear

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am brand new to SQL and am working with the following code provided to us by one of our vendors:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MriPatients.PatientID
INTO #UniquePt
FROM MriPatients
INNER JOIN #TotalPopulation ON MriPatients.PatientID = #TotalPopulation.PatientID
Set @TotalUniquePatients = (Select Count(*) FROM #UniquePt)
```

What happens is the Set line causes @TotalUniquePatients to be set to 0 even though there are many unique patient ids in our database.  That value is then later used as a denominator in a division which causes a divide by 0 error.

Now it seems to me that this is easy to fix by using COUNT DISTINCT on the MriPatients table; then you don't need to create #UniquePt at all...this is the only place that table is used.  But, I don't understand why the code as it is gets a 0 result when counting #UniquePt.  If you remove the INNER JOIN, the Set returns a correct result...so what does the INNER JOIN do to #UniquePt?

If it matters, we are using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: How is `#TotalPopulation` built? That's where I'd look next to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The result is 0 because of 1 of 2 situations:

- `#TotalPopulation` is empty
- `#TotalPopulation` contains no records that have the same value for `PatientID` as the records in `MriPatients`

How are you populating `#TotalPopulation`?

A `COUNT DISTINCT` won't necessarily do the same thing.  It depends on what you fill `#TotalPopulation` with.  If all you want is the number of unique patients in `MriPatients` then yes, the `COUNT DISTINCT` will work.  But if you're filling `#TotalPopulation` based on some kind of logic then they're the `COUNT DISTINCT` won't necessarily give you the same results as the `COUNT` of the joined tables.

Comment: Thanks much for the answers thus far, it's making more sense.  The problem is my currently limited understanding of what the inner join is doing :)
#TotalPopulation is, in fact, empty.  (It shouldn't be, but that's a different issue...)
This has been a huge help, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

The `INNER JOIN` causes you to insert **ONLY** records that have a matching `PatientID` in the `#TotalPopulation` table.

I'm guessing you don't, or that table isn't populated, which is causing the issue.

Is there a reason you are joining to it in the first place?